# [ROS2] How to enable spdlog logger?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know how to edit the logging format and logging level, but how to change the logger itself?

I was  searching and trying with `rclcpp::InitOptions options = rclcpp::InitOptions();` and  `rclcpp::init()` but I couldn't find anything regarding changing the logger itself.

I think this would be a good addition to the ros2 tutorials also.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339370/%5Bros2%5D-how-to-enable-spdlog-logger?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2019-12-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of eloquent, the default logger is spdlog!

---

Originally posted by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) with karma: 496 on 2020-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0